# How to import wasm into nextjs?

Tags: next.js, webassembly

Here is the repo to reproduce: https://github.com/voidcenter/import-wasm-into-nextjs

The wasm script is simple: https://github.com/voidcenter/import-wasm-into-nextjs/blob/main/rust-wasm/src/lib.rs

A simple way to import wasm into reactjs works: https://github.com/voidcenter/import-wasm-into-nextjs/blob/main/react-version/src/App.tsx#L2-L15

The same way however doesn't work in nextjs: https://github.com/voidcenter/import-wasm-into-nextjs/blob/main/nextjs-version/pages/index.tsx#L2-L15

The error is:

```
./public/js/gameplay.wasm
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
The module seem to be a WebAssembly module, but module is not flagged as WebAssembly module for webpack.
BREAKING CHANGE: Since webpack 5 WebAssembly is not enabled by default and flagged as experimental feature.
You need to enable one of the WebAssembly experiments via 'experiments.asyncWebAssembly: true' (based on async modules) or 'experiments.syncWebAssembly: true' (like webpack 4, deprecated).
For files that transpile to WebAssembly, make sure to set the module type in the 'module.rules' section of the config (e. g. 'type: "webassembly/async"').
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

The `next.config.js` is already configured to turn on `experiments.asyncWebAssembly`. https://github.com/voidcenter/import-wasm-into-nextjs/blob/main/nextjs-version/next.config.js

I followed a few pages online without success:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25852
- https://indent.com/blog/wasm-in-nextjs

Thanks